# Preventing copying/duplicating of a PHP/SQL database

Tags: php, javascript, sql, jquery

I am creating a store stock management PHP/SQL database which will be used on store's local server. Now I am stuck with a problem. How would I prevent someone from copying the database from my client PC to another PC without permission? How can we develop a database which only the developer can install? Some of the suggestions may be:

- to use machine codes etc for e.g the database will work on only one PC but still some one may alter the controller code and illlegaly copy it without the permission of the developer.
- Other suggestion may be to use a login system, but still the client may give the copy to others and share the login information.

So my question is:
Is there a good method to prevent illegal copying of a php/Sql database?

In other words:
Is there a way so that the database work in only the client PC/PC's, so that if someone copies it to other PC, it will not work?  Please Help!

Comment: There must be some way so that the database work in only one computer or in one network..

Comment: PHP and SQL have solutions for almost every programming problem, there must be some way, please help

Comment: This is a legal, not technological, problem.

Comment: What if the database required a database that was hosted on your computer, that only you would have access to, to work?

Comment: @Charlie thanks.. the client has its own local network.. so I can't implement this solution. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Why can't it connect to an outside network?

Comment: I have an idea.... if I add 2,3 hidden files on the server at time of installation of the database, and store their encrypted timestamps/location/other info in the database. The client usage of the database  would depend on those hidden filew and even if someone copies those files there timestamps will not match and the database would not work. Is this the proper method?

Comment: @Charlie its on a local intranet network. And the client wants it to be isolated from internet to prevent viruses/other risks etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly aapreciate the answers but as I was not getting a much proper solution in the present answers. After some research and keeping in view the answers, I have found a method to do it. We can create a database which is dependant on some encrypted hidden files or machine codes or keys etc in the client PC. We have to develop a script to applly those  secuirty measures(hidden files or machine codes or keys) at the time of database installation. The database should'not work without the  secuirty measures(hidden files or machine codes or keys) done properly.The developer should keep the installation script with him and use it at the time of installation of a database into the client PC. The database will not be installed without that script so no one would be able to install/copy the database without the developers permission. Keeping in view the answers and comments, It looks like the only easy way to do this.

Comment: I feel I have to point out one last time that what you are suggesting will take a lot of time and effort, will cause a lot of trouble if you ever have to recover your database, will be **extremely** difficult to maintain, and will be trivially easy for a hacker with even basic skills to bypass. If you still want to go forward with it I obviously cannot stop you, but I cannot emphasize enough that what you are trying to do is a **very** bad idea. It will ultimately cost you much more in reputation than what it will add in security. If you still must proceed then best of luck, you will need it.

Comment: @King Skippus hmm thanks for your suggestion... You are right... I live in a country where it is a custom to steal softwares and resold them. I am afraid I don't have any choice I just have to hope that the client doesn't give my software to others....

Comment: @King Skippus  When I was programming an assembly software for a microchip. There was a hardware option to easily lock the software so that no one can retrieve. It would have been nice if PHP has some method for such security. I think the only way left with me is that I keep usernames and Id's on my server. And if the server database keeps track of machine address of client pc's then only my clients computer could connect to server. And a stolen software would'nt work as the thief's PC's machine address will be different

Comment: @King Skippus  .... Well as with all other methods this mehod also may be not good choice as it makes all the clients and software dependant on one server. When server is down all clients will be effected. So as a conclusion we programmers don't have any choice for securing our softwares from theft when the software is on local server.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" solution for this is to

1. encrypt everything on your PC with a key that is not typed anywhere (your password)
2. lock your PC down so someone can't copy it.

If someone gets hold of the data, even encrypted, they would unencrypt if they wanted to. So stop them getting access to it is your best defence.

You could encrypt the data in the database also - but the key will be saved somewhere. If they get access to your PC, they get access to the unecryption keys. Other "programmed" defences (such as checking the computers hardware / registry keys etc) can be programmed round as well.

So this falls back to encrypting your PC as, hopefully, the encryption key isn't written down, and locking down so someone can't get the data in the first place.

Comment: thanks for the reply. You don't understood my point. The database will be installed on the client PC not my own PC. The client PC is not in developer's control..If the client gives your database illegally to someone, how to prevent them from using it.

Comment: Please check my edit. I have added some lines to better explain my question. So nice of you to answer but actually you didn't understood the question correctly. Kindly check the added explaination to my question

Comment: I have an idea.... if I add 2,3 hidden files on the server at time of installation of the database, and store their encrypted timestamps/location/other info in the database. The client usage of the database would depend on those hidden filew and even if someone copies those files there timestamps will not match and the database would not work. Is this the proper method?

Comment: The only way I can think of, then, is to modify the DB application itself to do something "different" with the data - most of the code is publicly available, so you could tweak and change the structure if you know how, and change the PHP drivers etc. This locks it to your own software installation. But get it wrong and you're in a mess. Otherwise everything has been said by others.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have a machine-specific installation of a database.  The best you can do is store it on an encrypted filesystem, take security precautions such as strong key-based authenticated access to the server, shutting off ports that aren't used, making sure the software is up-to-date, encrypting all communication between clients and the server, etc., and physically securing the machine.  (This is why, for example, Google's datacenters are so access-controlled with heavy security at the facilities are, and as a general rule, they don't even publish where their datacenters are located.)

And really, when you think about it, this is a *good* thing.  After all, what happens if the server crashes?  Do you *really* want there to be absolutely no way to restore the data to another server?

Security is important, but there is only so much it can do.  At some point, you're going to have to compromise based on practical considerations.

Comment: I understand that sometime we have to compromise on security, However I have an idea.... if I add 2,3 hidden files on the server at time of installation of the database, and store their encrypted timestamps/location/other info in the database. The client usage of the database would depend on those hidden filew and even if someone copies those files there timestamps will not match and the database would not work. Is this the proper method?

Comment: My first inclination is to think probably not.  If someone copies your database, they could simply issue a query to bypass any checking that takes place. Perhaps if the data inside the database is encrypted with some sort of signature like that it might be a bit more secure, but really, at that point, you might as well just hard-code a key in the source code. I'm just afraid that the hoops you're jumping through are going to bite you later when someone is trying to maintain or restore the database.

Comment: hmm thanks for the answer. I keep a record of every project. Using this method I have to note all the encryption data with me. So that I can easily restore the database in future

Comment: I understand your viewpoint. But we have to take some bold steps to stop thieves stealing our projects which are products of our hardwork.

Comment: This is a risk that everyone faces. I think that you are incurring more risk of irrevocable data loss by extreme measures. If you work for the CIA and people could literally be killed, I might understand. But for commercial data (credit card #s, client info, etc.), there is such a thing as too much security. What will happen if your notebook is accidentally destroyed, or if you die and no one knows how the data is encrypted? With all due respect, I would insist on means of recovery using industry standard best practices, not some weird proprietary measures. Still... *shrug... it's your choice.